# Make my facebook app (not a canvas app, its on website) work on https as well as on http, and with www. as well as without www

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

I have facebook app which is non canvas,the website URL of the app is specified without www.
Now when i goto my app with www.myapp.com the app doesnt work. and also also the same problem with protocol as well. so how do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like two thing.

1) Your DNS records are mixed up not allowing www.domain.tld and domain.tld being the same IP.

2) Your facebook app settings might have only www.domain.tld and not domain.tld specified in the App Domain setting.